# merge two datatables by looping through the rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

Hi All i have two datatable1 like this below format

```
 legacy                   subid                               converted     licPart         count
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC  CE E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OG EP E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC  CE E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OG EP E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-100  100
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU     7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC CE E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-1K   1000
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb   NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-1K   1000
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb   NL OG EP E-LTU    LIC-CP-EN-1K  1000
```

and i have another datatable2 like this

```
 ACCount    OBCount  OGCount        legacy
  50        25       25         Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU
  25        25       50         Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU
  375       375      250        Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU
```

and for the **result Table(merge with datatable1 and datatable2)** i am looking for like this below table

```
 legacy                   subid                               converted     licPart         count
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC  CE E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  50
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  25
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OG EP E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-100  25
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC  CE E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  25
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-100  25
Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL OG EP E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-100  50
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU     7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb  NL AC CE E-LTU   LIC-CP-EN-1K   375
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb   NL OB USR E-LTU  LIC-CP-EN-1K   375
Ent 1K EP Lic E-LTU    7ks7gp-qc42sn-g7zk0q-7pzmb7-xdp6yb   NL OG EP E-LTU    LIC-CP-EN-1K  250
```

if you observe the difference between first and last table is count column i need to merge the table 1 count with  table 2  AcCount , OBCount, OGcount for same legacy..

Could any one suggest any ideas and any suggestions that would be very greatful to me.

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you provide any sample output ?

Comment: @Mohammad please look into the last table (result table).. the difference is last column (count)

Comment: you have 2 entries for same legacy in table 2.How do you determine which count is to be merged?

Comment: @Mohammad the legacy column rows defined same as the table 1 only.. this row belongs  "NL AC  CE E-LTU"  to  "AC count" and same like as ..

Comment: @Mohammad here in table 2 we will be considered as single row where as in table 1 that we need to consider as single column change with respect to "Legacy" column

Comment: `SELECT [Table1].[legacy], subid, converted, licPart, [Table2].count FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.legacy = Table2.legacy`

Comment: @BassemAkl sorry i cannot use SQL here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Adding Convert Method**

Using LINQ, you can do the following:

```
    public class Table1
    {
        public string legacy, subid, converted, licPart;
        public int count;
    }
    public class Table2
    {
        public int ACCount, OBCount, OGCount;
        public string legacy;
    }

    private int Convert(string converted, int ACCount, int OBCount, int OGCount)
    {
        return converted.StartsWith("NL AC ") ? ACCount :
            converted.StartsWith("NL OB ") ? OBCount : OGCount;
    }

    private void JoinTables()
    {
        List<Table1> table1 = new List<Table1>();
        List<Table2> table2 = new List<Table2>();

        var result = from t1 in table1
                     join t2 in table2 on t1.legacy equals t2.legacy
                     select new Table1
                     {
                         legacy = t1.legacy,
                         converted = t1.converted,
                         licPart = t1.licPart,
                         subid = t1.subid,
                         count = Convert(t1.converted, t2.ACCount, t2.OBCount, t2.OGCount)
                     };
    }
```

Comment: sorry i need to consider all counts(ACCount, OBCount,OGCount) and merge with the corresponding columns.. here i am able to see only one count (i.e) ACCount

Comment: How do you consider them? What is your criteria? And you can insert it inside the join.

Comment: i need to represent the result table that i mentioned above (table 3 format) in the question .. could you please look into it ..

Comment: @EnigmaState, Ah OK. Then you parse the `converted` column.. if it contains (AC, OB, or OG), right? Any other conditions there?

Comment: no other conditions only we need to compare legacy column and merge the corresponding count rows

Comment: hi I am getting all double rows containing these sample values i should be able to get six rows containing these part id "Ent 100 EP Lic E-LTU" but i am getting 12 rows ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161163/discussion-between-bassem-akl-and-enigma-state).

Comment: Because you have in Table 2 the same legacy twice (in Row 1 and Row 2). Now, which one should be used? The join will use both.

Comment: hmm..  i need to use both and need to assign same as well.

Comment: would you please suggest on how to get only 6 rows according to table 1..

Comment: @EnigmaState, You will have to filter Table 2 to have distinct legacy. Then use the filtered new table to join with Table 1. But on which criteria you will choose to keep/remove rows from Table 2. It is up to your requirements.

Comment: but i need to keep these rows as sets  "NL AC CE E-LTU", " NL OB USR E-LTU", "NL OG EP E-LTU"

Comment: @EnigmaState, What do you mean? The converted column is already in the select statement!

Comment: never mind i got one more ID need to be added to second datatable but your idea is helped  me thanks  for your  support...